# Adding constant to function (vspace) argument?

Tags: calculations, dimensions, dimension-expressions

How can I get Latex to add a constant to a value as part of a `\vspace` argument?

Here's my minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
ab
%\vspace{20mm+10mm} %documentation of the calc package says it needs at least one dimen register
\newlength{\mylength}\setlength{\mylength}{20mm} \vspace{\mylength+10mm} 
\\cd
\end{document}
```

Which always produces *ab +10mm cd*.

Comment: `\vspace{\dimexpr\mylength+10mm\relax}`; but `\vspace{\mylength}\vspace{10mm}` is pretty much equivalent, because the second skip won't be used as a break point (unless `\lastskip` or `\unskip` are involved).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use eTeX's features.  Try the following

```
\vspace{\dimexpr\mylength+10mm\relax}
```

You won't need the `calc` package.